# Model prop, event in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I've Radio component, which uses `model` in export default.

```
<template>
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="radio__container">
      <input
        type="radio"
        :name="name"
        :value="value"
        :checked="isChecked"
        :disabled="disabled"
        @change="changeHandler"
        @input="inputHandler"
      />
      <slot name="checkmark" v-bind="{ isChecked, disabled }">
        <span class="radio__checkmark" />
      </slot>
      <span class="radio__content">
        <slot name="label" v-bind="{ label, isChecked, disabled }">
          <span class="radio__label" v-text="label" />
        </slot>
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Radio",
  model: {
    prop: "selected",
    event: "change",
  },
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    selected: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  computed: {
    isChecked() {
      return this.value === this.selected;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    changeHandler() {
      this.$emit("change", this.value);
    },
    inputHandler() {
      this.$emit("input", this.value);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I need to refactor it to vue 3 `<script setup>` and I don't know what to do with

```
model: {
  prop: "selected",
  event: "change",
}
```

Has anyone any suggestion?

Comment: Did you tried this one? https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits

Comment: yup, but it's not a problem. I've problem with model and don't know how to rectator it to vue 3

Comment: It doesn't seem to have a Composition API equivalent. Adding a separate `<script>` and keeping it as Options API might work. If it doesn't, it means it has been removed from Options API in Vue3 and you'll need to refactor the component as if `model` never existed.

Comment: Could you provide a *runnable* [mcve] of how your component was used in Vue2? Use codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: I came across the same issue. Have you solved refactoring custom model to vue 3 <script setup>?